# Does speeding increase the risk of accident?

Tags: safety, driving-speed

The article, [studies show higher speed limits do not increase accidents](http://www.ksl.com/?sid=26729407)
, claims that increased speeding does not increase your chance of falling into an accident.

However, another article [Speed and accident risk](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/wcm/road_safety/erso/knowledge/Content/20_speed/speed_and_accident_risk.htm)
 articulate the exact opposite:

> A higher speed increases the likelihood of an accident.

Note that I'm asking whether higher speeds increase the risk of getting an accident, not, does going above the speed limit increase risk.

Comment: 'Semi-lame looking.'

Comment: @Waterseas working in it/webdesign i like to call out trashy looking websites lol.

Comment: There are a couple questions about this already:  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/6424/19407 , http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/19915/19407

Comment: Of course it does! Why would anyone be skeptical of that? Give me one reason.

Comment: These are different notions; a speed trap is a road with a limit set significantly lower than its safe driving speed, for the purpose of spurring drivers to go over said limit and get a ticket.  This isn't the case elsewhere.

Comment: Speed increases stopping distance hugely and decreases the time in which to react to events on the road. Also, it doesn't necessarily need to be high speed that causes a crash - it is simply speed that is inappropriate for the conditions of the road and vehicle increase the likelihood of crash.